# Safely insert string into HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The insertion looks like this:

`a_span.innerHTML() = input.value`

To prevent any kind of attacks in PHP I use `htmlspecialchars`. Should I use [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars:426)
for protection or native `escape` is enough?

Comment: if your update remains client-side, I can't see why you would need to escape the input. Yet, you should escape when it is sumbited server-side and you need to execute the input (for table update for instance)

Comment: The update remains client-side, but if the user inputs some special chars, he will break the layout and it would be a bug

Comment: Yes, I think @JMax is right, no worries about the attacjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm assuming you intended to write `a_span.innerHTML = input.value`, since innerHTML isn't a function.

Secondly, you should use document.createTextNode() instead of innerHTML if you're worried about your text being interpreted as HTML entities. Something like `a_span.innerHTML="";a_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));` should work okay.